# Subquery returns more than 1 row in group by clause - MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join, group-by

I'm trying to get my expected result of my query with the correct sum of amount per date, however, the Amount keeps adding up when it detected the same ID. I want to get the group by date. Unfortunately, when I ran my query it's getting an error saying **Subquery returns more than 1 row**

Here's my query:

```
 SELECT a.DOB as `DATE`, (CASE when f.INHOUR > 12 or f.INHour = 12 Then 'PM' 
else 'AM' END) as Shift, concat(b.FIRSTNAME, ' ', b.LASTNAME) Fullname, 
a.Amount as DECLARED, SUM(c.Amount) as CALCULATED, 
a.AMOUNT as `NET OF SPECIAL SALES`, 
d.Amount as `CASH OVER SHORT`,
a.AMOUNT as `CASH DEPOSIT`,
(SELECT SUM(gndrevn.AMOUNT) from gndrevn where gndrevn.ID= b.ID and 
gndrevn.type = "4" group by gndrevn.DOB, gndrevn.ID) as `TRANSACTION COUNT (POS)`
FROM gndsale a 
INNER JOIN emp b ON a.ID= b.ID 
INNER JOIN gndsale c ON b.ID= c.ID
INNER JOIN gndsale d on b.ID = d.ID
INNER JOIN adjtime f on a.ID= f.ID
WHERE a.type = "22" AND c.type = "4" AND d.type = "42" and 
STR_TO_DATE(a.DOB, '%m/%d/%Y') BETWEEN '2017-05-01' AND '2017-05-31' GROUP BY DECLARED 
order by STR_TO_DATE(a.DOB, '%m/%d/%Y')
```

It returns this error:

[image]

I tried to remove  **gndrevn.DOB, gndrevn.ID**  and this is my result

[image]

The Column **Transaction Count POS** just added because it detected similar ID's in the table.

What the result I want for my Transaction Count POS is this:

[image]

I ran this with a different query, but it also requires a group by in a select statement

Here's the query:

```
SELECT ID as `EMPLOYEE`, sum(AMOUNT) as AMOUNT, DOB as DATE from gndrevn 
where ID in (select ID from gndsale) and type = "4" group by 
DOB, ID order by STR_TO_DATE(DOB, '%m/%d/%Y')
```

I think I have a problem with my group by statement to get the query. Anyone can help me on this? :(

Comment: Your query is in a mess.  The error message is clear: the subquery you have returns more than one record.  This needs to be fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is to remove the gndrevn.DOB from the GROUP BY and add gndrevn.DOB = a.DOB in the WHERE.

Comment: WOW! IT WORKED!! :D THANK YOU!!! :D  I havent thought of that :( I was thinking too deeply on my group by clause :(

Comment: While thinking deeply, I noticed that my CALCULATED column is out of sync as well.. its adding up records with the same ID, however, I want to determine it using date as well.... is this solution possible?

Comment: You can use the same method as before. Just replace the column and table name accordingly.

Comment: alright. I'll try to do it... I'll give you an update on my query later :) thanks again :)